# CORS Set-Cookie not works

Tags: cookies, cross-domain

My client served on `dev.cqyx.com:9798` and server on `api.cqyx.com:9797`
here is my request and response:

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://dev.cqyx.com:9798
Auth-Expiry:1478425298
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 06 Nov 2016 09:26:38 GMT
Refresh-Expiry:1481016398
Set-Cookie:AuthToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0Nzg0MjUyOTgsIkNzcmYiOiJvZDFVTXdsSm1YYWhMd2Q4VXVYc2x1MXUtMHNuTjVfYS0zdWdEMHRqSnYwPSIsIkN1c3RvbUNsYWltcyI6eyJSb2xlIjoidXNlciJ9fQ.LvYLoHZ6R_IuZ1aq0pedHpGRqJNI0xpKQmlgm9KDjqE; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie:RefreshToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0ODEwMTYzOTgsIkNzcmYiOiJvZDFVTXdsSm1YYWhMd2Q4VXVYc2x1MXUtMHNuTjVfYS0zdWdEMHRqSnYwPSIsIkN1c3RvbUNsYWltcyI6eyJSb2xlIjoidXNlciJ9fQ.l2Qdc8JsM9S23ogY705aLE5QhaICeILt8HRQttkQdzI; Expires=Tue, 06 Dec 2016 09:26:38 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
X-Csrf-Token:od1UMwlJmXahLwd8UuXslu1u-0snN5_a-3ugD0tjJv0=
```

and Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:6
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:api.cqyx.com:9797
Origin:http://dev.cqyx.com:9798
Referer:http://dev.cqyx.com:9798/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

I see the response return `Set-Cookie` but cookie doesn't setted actually, so why?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag `To accomplish this goal, browsers which support the secure flag will only send cookies with the secure flag when the request is going to a HTTPS page. Said in another way, the browser will not send a cookie with the secure flag set over an unencrypted HTTP request.`

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's it and thanks to figure it out~ It works now.